# pointer of an unsigned inter in python

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I am  working on python and `ctypes` of python.

I want to convert a given number to `ctypes.c_uint32` and then refer to its pointer as follows:

```
d = 0
d_c_unit32 = (ctypes.c_uint32 * 1)(d)
pd_c = ctypes.POINTER(d_c_unit32)
```

but I have an error which say:

> Detail TypeError: must be a ctypes type

would you please let me know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = 0
num = ctypes.c_uint32(d)
ptr = ctypes.pointer(num)
print 'pointer:', ptr
print 'value:', ptr[0]
```

Output is:

```
pointer: <__main__.LP_c_uint object at 0x7f4551c27680>
value: 0
```

Comment: It should be `ptr = int_pointer(num)` or `ptr = ctypes.pointer(num)`. Casting the address is wrong for two reasons. It doesn't reference the supporting object in the pointer's `_objects`. It's also relatively expensive because `ctypes.cast` is implemented as an FFI call.